# I'm getting "Missing \begin{document}" error but I have it

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[25pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{exscale} use to make larger symbols and signs
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[landscape,includefoot,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\pagestyle{plain}%for basic page numbers
\setcounter{page}{1}%begin with page proceeding previous lecture
\newcommand*{\dt}[1]{%use \dt instead of \cdot for bigger dots
\accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ddt}[1]{%use \ddt instead of \ddot for bigger double dots
\accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
content\\

\end{document}
```

Above are the lines of code I need for some lecture pdf's. I have already successfully produced one using these codes and I pasted them to a new document and now I'm getting `Missing \begin{document}`, even though I have it as well as `\end{document}`. I did not alter any of the codes so I don't understand why it's not working. I also tried deleting the aux files and such but it gives me the same error still.

Comment: Do you get that error with the above code? It compiles just fine here. (There is just an underfull hbox due to the `\\ ` after content, in general never use `\\ ` in the text.)

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why because I used the code for another document and it worked fine. But now I'm getting the error.

Comment: @Dr.A: Delete the `.aux` file and recompile...

Comment: I did but I still get the same error...

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: check to make sure the other document (1) still has the same preamble, and (2) still works.  if you've updated anything, there could have been an incompatibility introduced, so making sure the "old" file still works should trap that possibility.

Comment: Try setting TEXMFHOME=/some/non/existent/directory and compiling. If that works, it may be some configuration file in your home texmf tree which is causing the error. (Obviously this suggestion is inapplicable if you don't have such a tree.)

Comment: Well I started a new document now it works... Still don't know why it didn't compile before but thanks everyone for the inputs.

Comment: Perhaps your utf8-file started with a BOM.

Comment: yep, typical BOM issue...

Comment: I've closed as it's not really clear what the solution here is, although I'm with Ulrike on this.